# Importing in Cocoa, difference between '"' and '<'

Tags: cocoa, import

somehow I'm doing hard to figure out the difference between `#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>`
and `#import "Cocoa/Cocoa.h"`

is a '<' related to a framework, whereas '"' relates to classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `"` is used current directory is searched first for the header file, then other include directories (include paths with `-I` and default header paths). When `<` is used current directory is not searched (unless that is added with `-I`).

Comment: ahh so if I want to import a framework, it's better to use < ,as it doesn't search first within my current directory (which is pointless as the framework is not included there) but directly the included directories (where the framework is most likely to be found)

Comment: Yes, generally quote is used for our custom headers and < is used with library/framework headers.